# Internal server error in production with https in Django when change path

Tags: django, path, admin, production

I have changed the path for admin.site.urls to /admindjango, in local it works fine, but in production(https and domain) it gives error 500, I already enabled allowedhost '*' and debug=False.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admindjango/', admin.site.urls),
path('',
     include(('administracion.urls', 'administracion'), namespace='administracion')),
```

]

Answer (score 0):

It might be a lot of issues. Permission, server misconfigured, lack of db migration...

Without `.logs` we cannot help you at all. Go back to `Debug = True` and we'll see what happened.